# Remove white spaces in php output

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some php code. But it outputs some empty spaces in the **beginning** when I view the source code.

Can someone help me to remove it?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Here is my full code

```
<?php
include_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/wp-load.php';
function dt_query() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'order_guide',
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php $dt_array = array(); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
     $dt_array[] = array(
     'glazier' => get_field('glazier'),
     'brand'   => get_field('brand'),
     'pack'   => get_field('pack'),
     'size'   => get_field('size'),
     'description'   => get_field('description'),
     'code'   => '<a href="'.get_field('code').'">Download</a>',
     'cs_price'   => get_field('cs_price'),
     'split'   => get_field('split'),
     );
     ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;
echo maybe_serialize($dt_array); ?>
<?php }
dt_query();
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing so many PHP tags? Just enclose your PHP block in one set of open/close tags, and you'll get rid of the whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything between `<?php` and `?>` will be parsed by the PHP interpreter. Everything else is dumped to your output. And that is your problem. You often close `?>` followed by a new line and open `<?php`. Thus, the newline is written to your output and you'll end up with a lot of empty lines. So, why do you close and reopen your PHP workspace that often? Just include all PHP commands in a single PHP environment:

```
<?php
YOUR COMMANDS
MORE COMMANDS
EVEN MORE COMMANDS
[...]
?>
```

and the empty lines will vanish :)

Comment: This is not exactly correct. A new line after a closing `?>` is not sent to the browser. This is just the end of the line and it is ignored. In the code, there are also a few extra white spaces after at the least on closing `?>`. Strangely, a new line after the last closing `?>' in an included file will not be ignored. There must be a reason, but it is not logical at first, because it is ignored every where else, even at the end of the main script.

Answer (score 1):

[trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the string before the echo

Answer (score 1):

The spaces come from the whitespaces between the previous closing ?> tag and the next <?php tag.
Try removing all <?php and ?> tags, but keep the <?php tag on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $string

```
// one replcement
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);


// for all replacement.
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```